# How can I manually delete visual studio?

Tags: windows, installation

In my case I cannot run visual studio (2015).  It starts and just prints a white screen.  Interestingly everything is still on the screen, if I move to the top right hand corner the icon will change and it will read "close window".  I couldn't find a way to fix this so I just tried the obvious, reinstall.  Except I can't.  Any attempt to re-Install any version of Visual Studio, or to Maintain/Fix/Uninstall the existing version just results in the attached picture.  The zero body popup-box cannot be closed, except through task manager.

So I think at this point I have 3 possibilities.  Somebody can suggest another approach...  I can somehow find out how to manually uninstall Visual Studio...  or I delete everything and re-install everything, the whole operating system, from scratch.  I think the third option is the most likely, but am hoping that there are other options.
[image]

Comment: Via PowerShell, you may be able to do `Get-WMIOject Win32_Product | Where-Object Name -match "Visual Studio"` to see what is installed. Not sure how it installs as I don't use it. You then may be able to do the `.Uninstall()`  method. Does it not show in Control Panel? You may also be able to get the msiexec uninstall string via the registry and try that way.

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/vs2015/uninstall-visual-studio-2015/ also has some information

Comment: Thanks Backin.  The Microsoft link you included led me to the VisualStudioUninstaller tool.  It successfully removed the existing versions of VS.
Unfortunately for me, that wasn't enough.  When I try to reinstall them I get the same problem.  I've tried two media's for VS 2015 plus 2017.  It is very bizarre.  And unless someone can suggest any other option, I can't see any other possibility than reinstalling my laptop from scratch, and all the applications on it.